# OpenCV Object Tracking accurate enough to measure speed of conveyor precisely?

Tags: python, c#, opencv, image-processing, tracking

[image]

I am building a conveyor speed tracking system with only vision.
Basic concept of the project is to calculate conveyor's speed based on looking at the surface of the conveyor by camera.

**[What I Tried]**
By far, I tried to use OpenCV's object tracking algorithm to track each sections, but it seems that it's not accurate enough to calculate the speed. To normalize the speed variance, I created many tracking instances and get the speed average of the instances. However, even the average seems to be not consistent. For algorithm, I used MOSSE for the speed. When I use different algorithms such as KCF or CSRT, the process time is too slow for real-time speed tracking. I didn't try to use GOTURN yet as it requires a trained model.

Is object tracking in OpenCV not accurate enough? or is it just a problem in my algorithm?
Also, do you have any suggestion on how to precisely calculate conveyor's speed only by vision system?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: im not an expert on this, but make sure you didn't forget to take your frame rate into account, it's not a constant number

Comment: Set up a single, constant rectangular region of interest (ROI), and simply detect those black gaps(?) between the single sections. The width of the sections devided by the time between two detections of the black gaps should be conveyor's speed!?

Comment: can you post a link to the video? It'll let us try out our solutions and more clearly see what you're dealing with.